# Context aware Items of Comboxbox in DataGrid

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox, datagrid

Got a `DataTemplateColumn` in a `DataGrid` of a WPF application.
`DataTemplate` defines a `ComboBox`.
The list of items presented by the `ComboBox` needs to change based on the value of another field of bound `ItemsSource` for the same row that the `ComboBox` is in. I'm not using a `ComboBoxColumn` and cant for other reasons.

Currently have tried `Binding` the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` to an `ObjectDataProvider` in the xaml, and then setting the `MethodParameter` of the `ObjectDataProvider` in the `SelectionChanged` event handler of the `DataGrid`.

The `Combobox` items in respective rows update correctly when selected, however all other `ComboBoxes` rendered update also. Which causes the selected item of a previously set `ComboBox` in the previous row to clear. I suspect the other `ComboBoxes` update because they receive an `PropertyChanged` event from the `ObjectDataProvider` to which they are all bound.
I tried setting the `Binding Mode` on the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` to `OneTime`, but that did not help.

Any ideas on how to get the `ComboBox` to bind its `Items` when the `DataGrid Row` is selected, but not to rebind when another row (and subsequent `ComboBox`) is selected ?

Comment: If it's possible you can add into the `ViewModel` of the `DataGrid` item new property for `Combobox` `ItemsSource`. And bind this property instead of using `ObjectDataProvider`.

Comment: Sweet, in my case yes I have control over my VM, so I did as you suggested and it works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Added an additional IEnumerable property to the DataGrid bound Entity collection (plus logic to generate the items) and then Databound the ItemsSource of the ComboBox to that.
In My case I did not need to add a property to bind the Selecteditem to as I was already binding the SelectedValue and Text properties of the ComboBox.